# How do I stop creating a broken png when converting from base64 using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, base64, png

I've tried this a number of ways and have searched high and low, but no matter what I try (including all posts I could find here on the subject) I can't manage to convert my base64 string of an HTML document / canvas containing JavaScript.

I'm not getting the incorrect padding error which is quite common (I have ensured 'data:text/html;base64,' is not included at the start of the base64 string.)

I have also checked the base64 string both by checking and running the original .html file, which renders in browser with no issue, and decoding the string with an online decoder.

I know I must be missing something very simple here, but after several hours I'm ready to pull my hair out.

My encoding step is as follows:

```
htmlSource = bytes(htmlSource,'UTF-8')
fullBase64 = base64.b64encode(htmlSource)
```

The resultant base64 string is included in my attempts below, which should generate a turquoise oval with shadow on a dirty white background in 4k.

The following attempts all create a png file, only 1kb in size, which cannot be opened - 'It may be damaged or use a file format that Preview doesn’t recognise.':

```
import base64

img_data = b'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'

with open("turquoise egg.png", "wb") as fh:
    fh.write(base64.decodebytes(img_data))
```

Version 2

```
from binascii import a2b_base64

data = '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'
binary_data = a2b_base64(data)

fd = open('turquoise egg.png', 'wb')
fd.write(binary_data)
fd.close()
```

Version 3

```
import base64
  
fileString = 'PCFET0NUWVBFIGh0bWw+CjxodG1sPgogIDxoZWFkPgogICAgPG1ldGEgbmFtZT0ndmlld3BvcnQnIGNvbnRlbnQ9J3dpZHRoPWRldmljZS13aWR0aCwgaW5pdGlhbC1zY2FsZT0xLjAnPgogIDwvaGVhZD4KPGJvZHk+CjxzdHlsZT4KICAgIGJvZHksIGh0bWwgewogICAgICBwYWRkaW5nOiAwICFpbXBvcnRhbnQ7CiAgICAgIG1hcmdpbjogMCAhaW1wb3J0YW50OwogICAgICBtYXJnaW46IDA7CiAgICB9CiAgICAqIHsKICAgICAgcGFkZGluZzogMDsKICAgICAgbWFyZ2luOiAwOwogICAgfQo8L3N0eWxlPgoKPGNhbnZhcyBpZD0nbXlDYW52YXMnIHN0eWxlPSdvYmplY3QtZml0OiBjb250YWluOyB3aWR0aDogOTl2dzsgaGVpZ2h0OiA5OXZoOyc+CllvdXIgYnJvd3NlciBkb2VzIG5vdCBzdXBwb3J0IHRoZSBIVE1MNSBjYW52YXMgdGFnLjwvY2FudmFzPgoKPHNjcmlwdD4KdmFyIGNhbnZhcyA9IGRvY3VtZW50LmdldEVsZW1lbnRCeUlkKCdteUNhbnZhcycpOwpjYW52YXMud2lkdGggPSA0MDk2OwpjYW52YXMuaGVpZ2h0ID0gNDA5NjsKY2FudmFzLnN0eWxlLndpZHRoID0gJzk5dncnOwpjYW52YXMuc3R5bGUuaGVpZ2h0ID0gJzk5dmgnOwp2YXIgY3R4ID0gY2FudmFzLmdldENvbnRleHQoJzJkJyk7CnZhciBjYW52YXNXID0gY3R4LmNhbnZhcy53aWR0aDsKdmFyIGNhbnZhc0ggPSBjdHguY2FudmFzLmhlaWdodDsKCmN0eC5maWxsU3R5bGUgPSAncmdiYSgyMDAsIDE5NywgMTc3LCAxKSc7CmN0eC5maWxsUmVjdCgwLCAwLCBjYW52YXNXLCBjYW52YXNIKTsKCmN0eC5zaGFkb3dCbHVyID0gY2FudmFzVzsKY3R4LnNoYWRvd0NvbG9yID0gJ3JnYmEoMCwgMCwgMCwgMC4zKSc7CmN0eC5iZWdpblBhdGgoKTsKY3R4LmZpbGxTdHlsZSA9ICdyZ2JhKDUxLCAyMjAsIDE5MSwgMSknOwpjdHguZWxsaXBzZShjYW52YXNXIC8gMiwgY2FudmFzSCAvIDIgLCBjYW52YXNXICogLjQsIGNhbnZhc0ggKiAuNDUsIDAsIDAsIDIgKiBNYXRoLlBJKTsKY3R4LmZpbGwoKTsKCgoKPC9zY3JpcHQ+Cgo8L2JvZHk+CjwvaHRtbD4='
  
decodeit = open('turquoise egg.png', 'wb')
decodeit.write(base64.b64decode((fileString)))
decodeit.close()
```

FWIW I originally used the following code to create a png from the HTML without using base64, but it would only ever save the first element of JavaScript generated on the canvas (ie the background) and since I require the information in base64 anyway, thought I would approach it this way in order to capture the complete image

```
file = open('html.html', 'r')
    
imgkit.from_file(file, 'png.png')
file.close()
```

Comment: The data represented by the Base64-encoded data is an HTML fragment. Of course you cannot create a valid PNG by saving this into a file and telling your computer that it is a PNG file, because it isn't. The problem is not with this code; the problem is with what `htmlSource` contains **before** this code. "I can't manage to convert my base64 string of an HTML document / canvas containing JavaScript." Well, yes; you didn't **start** with a PNG, so encoding to base64 and decoding back from base64 doesn't give you a PNG.

Comment: If you want to get the PNG that results from *running that Javascript to draw things on a canvas*, then you need to *actually have the Javascript run and draw things on the canvas*. Then you can use a feature *of your web browser* to capture the image. Alternately, fix the Javascript so that it actually *creates* a data URL, and put it somewhere that you can capture - for example, `console.log` it and copy it from the browser console; or write a local file from the Javascript (the browser must give permission). All of these are topics to *research* before asking.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond. What you say makes complete sense and I wish I’d carried on with my initial method using imgkit, I was just drawn in by the level of support for converting using base64.
I researched as far as I could including trying troubleshooting imgkit and bokeh solutions, but without the pointers you’ve given I hit a dead imgkit.
Thanks to your guidance I’ve come across html2image and it has provided the solution I was looking for (added to question for reference)

Comment: base64 is an important tool for dealing with image data on the Internet - it just doesn't address *this* problem.

Answer (score 1):

Html2Image has provided the solution I was looking for.

Whilst imgkt wasn't saving the fully rendered canvas, taking  screenshot with html2canvas does. Documentation is [here](https://pypi.org/project/html2image/) and I implemented as follows:

```
from html2image import Html2Image

    hti.screenshot(
        html_file = ‘html.html’, 
        size = (imageW, imageH),
        save_as = ‘png.png'
    )
```